# Excel formula for subtraction common item need to minus previous minus qty

Tags: excel-formula

I need an excel formula for required. example I have an rupees 60000 I'm just given to my friends to spilt the amount each 20000 thousand but forget given one member two times amount issued.

I need to subtract  on this amount below criteria.

[image]